# Lightroom added new subfolder, messes up path

Tags: lightroom

In my path `~NZ/1October/11th of October/Raw` there are supposed to be RAW files. Instead Lightroom added an extra folder, `~NZ/1October/11th of October/Raw/Raw`.

Why does Lightroom add this additional subfolder? And do I have to go "Missing Folder" on every subfolder to have my pictures in Lightroom again?

Comment: Can you explain how you import your images in Lightroom? What is the "Missing folder" you are talking about?

Comment: I'm dragging the pictures from Finder (OS X) to Lightroom, choosing "Add->Import". That way, all pictures are organised in OS X. The should be in a folder on my desktop, with the last two folders being named "11th of October/RAW". Instead it's "11th of October/RAW/RAW". If I choose "Missing Folder" on every extra RAW-folder I can point them on the right folder, but that would have to be done 60 times, and I don't learn anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which version of LR that you are using, but I do know that unless you are very careful, LR will create new (default) import folders in a date-based folder hierarchy. If you unwittingly re-import the same images, LR will keep creating new subfolders. Remember to check the box marked "Do not import suspected duplicates" as one of your import preferences.

I use LR 5.7 for windows in which one of the import options is to keep the imported images in their original folder. If you have an automatically  synced, cloud-based account, then you must carefully review the import and sync options. In LR 5.7, you must right click individual missing folders and search within the suspected missing master folder. However, if the other missing folders are within that same master folder, LR will automatically find them all in the same step.